# iOS memory utilization readings

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I'm trying to get memory utilization data at runtime and I can't seem to find anything that corresponds to the readings available in the xCode profiler - https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6npP.jpg.  Are these available at runtime?  I've tried using mach_port_t data, inspecting active_count, inactive_count, wire_count, and free_count, but nothing seems to be adding up correctly.  I've ensured that I'm properly converting page count to megabytes.

Thanks

Comment: Because the application runs in a sandboxed environment I don't think it's possible to get information like that unfortunately, I think the readings you will get would be limited to the resource your application has access to and not system wide

Comment: Thanks.  I had a glimmer of hope since some bug tracking tools (like Crittercism) seem to be reporting usage correctly.  I guess they're just making educated guesses.

Comment: Hmm okay.. I might be wrong in that case but I've never managed to see anything that correctly reported that myself. Sorry I can tell further

Answer (score -1):

`Instruments` would provide you much more in-depth information about your app. From your screenshot press `Profile in Instruments`

Comment: I'm actually trying to get these values in code at runtime.  I want to be able to get the data in the screenshot from within the app for reporting.